# Recaptcha won't render using sfFormExtraPlugin and JQuery Dialog (lightbox)

Tags: jquery, symfony1, dialog, recaptcha

Morning. I have a form which is rendered inside of a jquery dialog box (lightbox) and currently trying to implement recaptcha as part of the form. Because I am using the symfony framework I am able to use the sfFormExtraPlugin which includes a recaptcha widget. This widget renders fine if I echo as part of the original page, but it will not render when inside the jquery dialog box.

After some investigating, I found the script that recaptcha creates looks similar to the following:

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    site : '6Let7r0SAAAAAJFp77tW4gRze7r5y89Cql_msPcm',
    challenge : '03AHJ_VusnO7jeI3VF-cHgOIv9RY9RIpYl2QWea_LULIdL8xrM9PZdcZZ7I9gFf4gSbr1fxGCSQjQZPJQ1sa6p1oEI9U_nkU8f2SjczxjH6nzmy43Q-m_8rnxWhhRUIDa7iTPEwo4-dwi-FipyMHsSAz-nE5yfFQfZog',
    is_incorrect : false,
    programming_error : '',
    error_message : '',
    server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    timeout : 18000
};

document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

I think the problem is the document.write, b/c the javascript is being invoked within the jquery dialog box vs the actual document, so the document.write won't work as expected.

Thoughts?

-- Edit --

Posted final solution on my [blog](http://melikedev.com/2011/05/24/symfony-add-recaptcha-to-jquery-dialog-lightbox/), I would have posted here but it is fairly involved.

Comment: if your lightbox is filled with the response of an AJAX request, the javascript inside the response might not be executed... could you show us how your lightbox works? Also, could you show us the html you can see when you inspect the widget with Firebug?

Comment: @greg0ire: you are correct. It is b/c the document.write js is not being executed. I'll post my results when complete. I got the lightbox to render the recaptcha widget, just working on the validation now.

Comment: Posted link to final solution via edit. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit of the OP, I was able to finally figure out a solution.